# Show child SKU on sales order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

In Magento, by default, the sales order items for configurable products are showing the parent product SKU. How can we show the child product SKU for configurable products? I have tried changing the code in the function at vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Items/Column/DefaultColumn.php

```
public function getSku()
    {

        return $this->getItem()->getSku();
    }
```

to

```
public function getSku()
    {

        return $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getData('sku');
    }
```

But it still shows the parent SKU.

Comment: can you confirm the behavior on default magento, I have checked the default magento(2.4.5) where i have confirmed it will show your child product SKU only

Comment: Yes. I am using ver. 2.3.4